# I have copied the ansible "copy" module to the project but the copied module does not work

Tags: ansible

I have developed the ansible modules.

I have copied the ansible's copy module's source code copy.py to the project's root directory as c_copy.py("c_copy" module), and execute the task used the "c_copy" module. As a result, I can't understand but the task have failed although the task used the "copy" module have suceeeded.
It seems that the "c_copy" module can't find files in the role's files directory.

So, please tell me why "c_copy" module does not work at well.

---

To ask your help, I have created the github repository.

https://github.com/suzuki-shunsuke/ansible-module-test-example

You can check my source code and reproduce my problem.

### Requirements to reproduce

- Python 2.7.12(pyenv)
- pip
- Vagrant(My Vagrant version is 1.8.6)

### Setup

```
$ git clone https://github.com/suzuki-shunsuke/ansible-module-test-example
$ cd ansible-module-test-example
$ pyenv install 2.7.12
$ pip install --upgrade pip
$ pip install --upgrade virtualenv
$ virtualenv env
$ source env/bin/activate
$ cp env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/files/copy.py c_copy.py
```

### Test

```
$ vagrant up --provision-with=ansible
```

### ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
library = .
```

### tasks/main.yml

```yaml
- name: run the copy module
  copy:
    src: test.txt
    dest: /tmp/test.txt
- name: run the clone of the copy module
  c_copy:
    src: test.txt
    dest: /tmp/c_test.txt
```

### Result

```
TASK [copy : run the copy module]  **********************************************
changed: [default]

TASK [copy : run the clone of the copy module]  *********************************
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Source test.txt not found"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some modules are wrapped with action plugins.
[Here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py) is one for copy module.

So when you call `copy`, Ansible executes action plugin `copy`, which in turn calls `copy` module.
When there is no action plugin, module with the same name called directly.

If you look into `copy` action plugin code, you'll notice a bunch of file handling stuff, that your `c_copy` module omits.

Try to duplicate action plugin code and test your setup again.

Comment: Hi, Konstantin Suvorov.
Thank you so much!
My problem has been solved!
I will read the official plugin's source code and documents.

Comment: Hi, Konstantin Suvorov.
Thank you for the other day.

Thanks to you, I have been able to create the ansible module and action plugin.

https://galaxy.ansible.com/suzuki-shunsuke/ghq-module/

Thank you again.